# Form Element Missing from DOM in IE7

Tags: html, dom, internet-explorer-7

Why doesn't IE7 load `<form>` tags into the DOM? It is causing issues with CSS that I had applied to a class on the form tag. I solved the issue by wrapping the form tag with a div, and applying the styles to that, but I wanted to see if anyone could offer a technical explanation of what IE is doing with this tag when I use the following code;

```
<form class="contact"> ... <form>
```

Causes issues in IE7, as well as

```
<div class="contact"><form class="contact"> ... <form></div>
```

I had to use

```
<div class="contact"><form> ... <form></div>
```

To solve my issue, but some minor inconsistencies remain. **This question isn't about my layout issue**, but just in case you are wondering, the CSS I was using is;

```
html {
    background: #113333;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    background: #ccc;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

div { background: green; }

.contact {    
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}

fieldset {
    float: left;
}
```

Also the page this relates to (content may change) is [here](http://jsprague.deltagroup.com/forms/contact.html).

So, what is IE7 doing with code like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I documented this bug [here](http://work.arounds.org/issue/71/forms-cant-receive-borders-ie-unless-explicit-body/). You basically need `<body>` or you can't style form elements in IE pre 8/9.

Comment: Oops. Copy paste error, I hadn't even noticed that I didn't have a body tag. I feel kind of stupid now. Interesting behavior though. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, really interesting behaviour. A little experimentation with your test case in Hixie's Live DOM Viewer ( http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/saved/737 ) shows that although the form can be styled, the DOM is really retarded, even in IE9 PP6!

Comment: @Alohci - that's a sweet utility.

Comment: That's interesting. I was playing around with that utility in IE9, and it seems that if a <form> is the first thing in the "body" when there is no closing </head>, IE puts the <form> in the <head>. If you put a <p> before the <form>, IE gets smart and puts everything in the <body>.